# I don't know how to be able to view my object normally again

Tags: mesh

[image: my view right now]

So this is what I see now, but I cant get the bottom part (that's orange right now) to be viewed normally again, like the top part.
I have no idea how this happened and I tried to google the problem but I am unsure what has even happened so I don't really know what to look for.

Can anyone explain what I can do to fix this?

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner.

Comment: Probably the rendering of the torus is limited to "wired". If that, look at this object's property panel, in the display section and check "maximum draw type"

Comment: Is there only one object in place? Probably there're 2 of them, one is drawn as wire, another one as solid. Or maybe some modifiers on the objectm could you show screenshot with modifier stack for the selected object shown?